# Background size with UIButton containing image above the text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have an image displaying correctly above the text and the selected background is the correct size thanks to a wee hack (looping over the subviews).

**The problem** is with the coloured background springing back to the frame of the text, and then animating back to the correct size.

How can I prevent this strange background animation?

[image]

```c
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGFloat marginTop = 0;
    CGFloat marginBottom = 0;

    CGSize titleSize = self.titleLabel.frame.size;
    self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(  - (titleSize.height - marginTop),
                                              0.0,
                                              0.0,
                                              - titleSize.width);

    CGSize imageSize = self.imageView.frame.size;
    self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(  0.0,
                                              - imageSize.width,
                                              - (imageSize.height - marginBottom),
                                              0.0);

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && ![view isEqual:self.imageView]) {
            view.frame = self.bounds;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think some animation is committed at somewhere. As you are using some view-hierarchy hack, then it might be hidden.

Try to avoid animation by calling [`setAnimationsEnabled:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationsEnabled:) method.

```
   [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
   for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && ![view isEqual:self.imageView]) {
            view.frame = self.bounds;
        }
    }
   [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

Beware. This is another hack based on global state, and may cause even worse side effect.